# Time Machine without Airport?

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine

I'm a **very** new Mac user. I just bought a MacBook Pro and I'd like to use the Time Machine backup. Unfortunately, it seems like I can only keep my laptop mobile by using an Airport router. I was hoping that I could backup to a HDD shared by my Window 7 desktop.

Is this pie in the sky? Is there a backup alternative that I could use that would give me the functionality I'm looking for?

**Additional Information**

I'm not looking to back up files per se. My documents, pictures, etc, are backed up on mirrored externals on my PC. I'm looking for a backup that will allow me to restore my applications and their settings should the Mac ever crash - installing and configuring a system is the most time consuming part of rebuilding a machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm running Lion, and TimeMachine uses a different file transfer (AFP), I ended up setting up a FreeNAS box, and hooking a cheap WD HDD to it.

If I wasn't running Lion, I could have simply shared the WD HDD from my Windows 7 machine. The AFP protocol adds a bit of complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Time machine requires a specially formatted hard drive - it doesn't have to be an Apple drive and indeed can be anything you can connect to the machine, but it must be HFS+ and as such cannot be shared by Windows (FAT/NTFS).

My choice in this situation (I too have a W7 machine too) was to purchase a relatively cheap Western Digital Portable HDD from Amazon, let my Mac format that and use it exclusively for backups. I couldn't find anything to share them between machines at all.

If you're only looking to backup files, however, [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) may suit you well. It's free plan provides you with a 2gb folder that syncs between your computers (and the cloud).

I'm interested in what you said about an Airport router - your Macbook should be able to connect to any Wifi A/B/G network (so pretty much anything, for instance the free router your internet supplier provides).

Comment: I have an available 500gb external HDD to use for backup. The problem is that I don't want to tie my laptop to a USB HDD. I'd love for TM, or another backup solution, to work wirelessly.

Comment: This is similar to what I originally wanted to attain. I haven't found a good way of doing it, although I presume if you setup a NAS drive as a time machine it'll act exactly the same as the Apple Time Machine does - does the 500 you have support NAS configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's a cheap Western Digital. I could plug it in every night before bed, but I don't know what time machine would think of that.

Comment: Oh it'll handle that just fine - that's what I do, it'll just see time machine as being plugged in and get started backing up. I keep my external in my computer bag and backup when I finish every evening.